# php email is not moving to my personal mail (google, yahoo)

Tags: php, email

i am facing a problem that i am sending a mail from my php form is showing that message sent but it is not reflecting in my personal mail. i ve been searching for the solution find simple email form, even i can't get the exact solution. if anybody knows the solution kindly share and help.

```
<?php
function spamcheck($field)
  {
    $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }

if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
  {
  $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['email']);
  if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
    {
    echo "Invalid input";
    }
  else
    {
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
    mail("someone@gmail.com", "Subject: $subject",
    $message, "From: $email" );
    echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "<form method='post' action='mailform.php'>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text'><br>
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
  Message:<br>
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br>
  <input type='submit'>
  </form>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Try to check your spam directory.

Comment: You need to configure SMTP on your server

Comment: `email()` will return `true` on success. But u don't check whether the function is returning `true` or not...

Comment: Check your spam box ?

Answer (score 0):

To have a better structure (PHP 5 object), try to use SwiftMailer : http://swiftmailer.org/

```
        require_once('swiftBundle/lib/swift_required.php');

        $body='your HTML';

        // SMTP
        $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Subject Mail')
        ->setFrom(array('mail' => 'name'))
        ->setTo(array('mail' => 'name'))
        ->setBody($body);

        $type = $message->getHeaders()->get('Content-Type');
        $type->setValue('text/html');
        $type->setParameter('charset', 'utf-8');

        $result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: dear donavan charpin, thanks for your immediate response, but the problem is, i am not even much familliar with frameworks and i am a pure core php developer. help me to perform this mail task. thanks again

Comment: You gave just to put the archive on tout workspace, after mâle link with include and copy past my code to create tout mail. Juste change values.

Comment: Warning: require_once(swiftBundle/lib/swift_required.php): failed to open stream: again i face this error...

Comment: the path `swiftBundle/lib/swift_required.php` is relative to your php file where you have copy paste my code. Check if this path is correct. Maybe you have put the bundle in a php folder, so will be `php/swiftBundle/lib/swift_required.php`. If you still have error, check rights on your path